# Grid View single child drawable animation

Tags: android, android-layout

> hello , i want to drawable animation for only grid view single child
> but i could not  find the proper solution for this

[image]

> this is sample pic where you can see the red circle , i just want the
> drawable animation for that grid view child [red circle image].

Thanks....

Comment: You need code for animation or you are having problem to set animation for single grid.

Comment: having problem to set animation for single grid........

Comment: You can set in getView() method by checking the position of grid

Comment: yes i do but Null Pointer exception arise.....

Comment: can you put your code where exception occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution .....

i just write the following code into getView method of Adapter class

```
if (position == 0) {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frame);
                mAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) v.getBackground();
                v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (mAnimation != null)
                            mAnimation .start();
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
```